# Sense HAT LED matrix displays incorrectly

Tags: python, sense-hat

When I try to light up one pixel at a time, the whole column lights up. This happens no matter what color I set it to. The rainbow when the pi boots up is also distorted since the columns are lighting up. Is this a problem I could fix, or is my display a goner? I'm using a RPi 3 if that matters.

Edit: I mean when I try to light up just one pixel with a color (for example red) the entire column is lighting up with that color. I know the code is correct because I tested it in the emulator. I'm wondering if this is some kind of connection issues or if I have a faulty board.

Here's the code (as per the API available vi a Foundation URL: https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/sense-hat/ link to the page containing this https://pythonhosted.org/sense-hat/api/#set_pixel ):

```
from sense_hat import SenseHat

sense = SenseHat()

sense.clear()
sense.set_pixel(0, 0, 255, 0, 0)
```

Comment: Please add the code you're using to your question

Comment: Welcome to the Raspberry Pi flavoured corner of the Stack Exchange network, you might wish to take the [tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) to get more information about the best way to use this site.  I have edited the question to provide a link to the API documentation - which does suggest to me that the code should do what you say: i.e. it should light up just one pixel (of the 8 rows by 8 columns) in the corner {the (0, 0) one} in red - why it doesn't is not obvious to me either!